# Spring Boot disable security for tests

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to create a REST Api with Spring-Boot and I need to disable security for testing purposes. I want to be able to use PostMan without any security constrain.

I have tried several ways but nothing seems to work it's as if the AplicationTest configurations are never applied.

This is the code for my **ApplicationTest** class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration()
public class ApplicationTests {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplicationBuilder ab = new SpringApplicationBuilder(ApplicationTests.class);

        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("server.port", 9999);
        properties.put("security.basic.enabled", false);
        properties.put("security.enable-csrf", false);

        ab.properties(properties);
        ab.run(args);
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {  
            http.httpBasic().disable();
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my **SecurityConfig** class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.app")
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // @formatter:off
        http
            .httpBasic().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/business/**").hasAnyRole("BUSINESS", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/api/users/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/api/admins/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            ShaPasswordEncoder encoder = new ShaPasswordEncoder();
            auth.userDetailsService(authenticationService).passwordEncoder(encoder);
    }
}
```